# Swift indexpath.row extract single string

Tags: ios, swift, string, segue

How do I extract a single string from indexPath.row? I am populating a tableview with users from Firebase and need to grab and pass the "uid" into another view controller.

My current try...

```
 if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]?.value(forKey: "uid")
                let controller = segue.destination as? ExploreBusinessProfileSwitchView
                controller?.otherUser = user
            }
```

Comment: What does your current code do? How does that differ from your goal?

Comment: What kind of objects does your usersArray contain? Edit your question to show that structure, and explain the problem with your current code.

Comment: `usersArray[indexPath.row]["uid"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just check this hope this explains what you exactly need

[image]

In Swift

Use

```
var swiftUserImages : [[String:Any]]?
swiftUserImages![indexPath]["uid"]
```